# How Do I Execute A Stored Procedure From A BizTalk SendPort?

Tags: sql, wcf, biztalk, port, send

I would like to call a stored procedure from a SendPort. I want to avoid an orchestration and instead, create a subscription to the message box based on the receive port and message type. I also need to use attributes from the received message xml as parameters for my stored procedure.

My assumption is that I should use WCF-SQL adapter. However, the only examples I have found require a 20 step process and some magic/luck... oh yeah, and an orchestration. Am I crazy for thinking this should be way simpler than it seems? Can anyone provide me with resources or advice?

Answer (score 2):

Is one of the examples you looked at the excerpt from Richard Seroter's book?
http://www.packtpub.com/article/soa-capabilities-in-bizTalk-wcf

What you want to do can be done without an Orchestration.

Comment: I guess I can appreciate how this article is trying to explain how WCF is the greatest thing since sliced bread, but it's kind of shotgun approach to covering a very straight forward topic. 

Why does it seem like executing a query is like learning to speak friggin' Russian? Does Microsoft even want me to use SQL Server with BizTalk or what?

Still not sure I get what the heck I need to do.

Comment: I can try and walk you through it, do you have the adapter pack v2.0 installed?

Comment: Sorry for venting a little. Just frustrated this is so complicated. Yes, I have the adapter pack installed and currently using WCF-SQL adapter for receiving data via XML polling.

Comment: Ha, no problem.  I was going to try and list the steps here but it became sort of a mess.  I'll try and throw a quick example together this weekend.  I have to do this exact same thing for a project so I need a refresher myself.